# Wanted: Female contributor(s) for Eschewmenical

Tags: discussion, blog

We are looking for a female contributor or two to help us give a different perspective on our new Christianity.SE blog.

This month's topic is contraception and we have quickly realized that all of our contributors are male. This seems like an incomplete treatment of the issue of contraception and we feel like dealing with the issue without hearing from women (preferably on both sides of this issue) would be unfair both to women and to the topic.

Personally I would love it if a woman or two (or more) would come forward to be a regular contributor to our blog, but I would understand if they would prefer a more occasional role.

Please post an answer here or join our blog chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room)

Answer (score 1):

> This month's topic is contraception.

Suggestion: Talk about something else this month, and save contraception till you have someone on the team qualified to talk about it.

Comment: The topic is not really contraception as an abstract concept, but the [role of contraception within the family](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/927/4) as seen through the particular Christian denomination. What licenses or liberties ought to be granted to married couples. Why some churches allow contraception and others don't, etc...  It's not really about the personal aspect of regulating birth nor is it about the term birth control itself, which, [as Chesterton wrote](http://www.gkc.org.uk/gkc/books/on_evil_euphemisms.html), promotes neither birth nor self-control.

Comment: @PeterTurner. Sounds pretty abstract to me. "It's not really about the personal aspect of regulating birth" is precisely my point.

Comment: I think that's because you're not married, it would be a pertty abstract concept to me too if I were the solitary man.  But it's not about the individual aspect, it's about the mutual aspect.  (I think I used personal in the wrong sense. I meant individual, not just private)